# Infinitely many zeros of a nonconstant continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a nonconstant continuous function. Is $S=\{x: f(x)=0\}$ finite?

I have thought of a function with countably many $0$'s like lots of triangular bumps at each point $\{1/n\}$, I mean lots of $W/M$ shapes on $[0,1]$. Is it okay?

Comment: Any closed subset of metric space can be a zero set of continuous function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your suggestion will work well. If you want an explicit formula, look at $f(x)=x\sin(1/x)$ when $x\ne 0$, and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: As always, very nice @AndréNicolas. Beat me to it by seconds. :) +1

Comment: I have become accustomed to stopping typing because you have already answered. But usually you are faster by more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)=\max\{0,2x-1\}$ is a nonconstant continuous function with uncountably many zeros.

Comment: would you explain a bit?

Comment: @miosaki: It could also be thought of as a piecewise defined function as follows: If $0\leq x\leq\frac12$, then $f(x)=0$.  If $\frac12\leq x\leq 1$, then $f(x)=2x-1$.  It stays at $0$ until $x=\frac12$, then ramps up to $1$.